# Intel Gallileo or Arduino Yun?

Tags: intel, sap-erp, sap-business-technology-platform, intel-galileo, arduino-yun

What are the main differences between the Arduino Yun and Gallileo Intel?
Which one do you recommend me to buy?

I want to use it for IoT projects, I want to be able to connect it to the SAP and Intel Platform as a service.

**EDIT** (from OP comment):

> *"I mean HANA Cloud platform (which is able to integrate your ERP 6.0 with IoT)"*

Comment: Intel Galileo may run a full-featured up-to-date Linux kernel (see https://github.com/dmarkey/galileo-resurrection). Arduino is much simpler. Speaking of weigth categories in box, these two boards in the light and heavy weight categories, you can't compare them as is, it will make no much sense.

Answer (score -1):

There is very good discussion on the Arduino forum, wherein both have been compared to each other. Check this [link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=223991.0).

For the second part of your question, could you elaborate more on exactly what is your usecase and exactly how do you want to connect to SAP?

Also by SAP, I guess, you meant the SAP ERP 6.0?

Comment: I meant HANA Cloud platform (which is able to integrate your ERP 6.0 with IoT)